# Propel reverse engineering

Tags: php, pdo, propel

Gone through a number of questions and none of the solutions have worked for me. Hopefully someone has some insight.

Here's my build.properties file

```
propel.project = league

propel.database = mysql

propel.database.url = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leaguerunner'
propel.database.user = root
propel.database.password = root
```

Propel version is 2.0.0-alpha2, PDO is installed and validated to work using thse parameters, PHP version is 5.4.4.

```
> propel reverse
Schema reverse engineering failed. You can use the --verbose option to get more information.

>propel reverse --verbose mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leaguerunner mysql:dbname=leaguerunner
Reading database structure...
There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
Schema reverse engineering failed.

>propel reverse --verbose mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leaguerunner                        
Reading database structure...
There was an error building XML from metadata: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
Schema reverse engineering failed.
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the single quotes around `'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=leaguerunner'` and give a shot ?

Comment: I did, yes. Originally there were no single quotes, and I've tried none, single, and double repeatedly.

Comment: Looks like it's failing to connect to the DB, make sure you've defined your **buildtime-conf.xml**, **runtime-conf.xml** files and declared them in your build.properties

Answer (score 1):

"propel reverse" is for Propel 2.0, but build.properties is for Propel 1.*.

You should use one of the config possibilities that offers Propel 2.0:
http://propelorm.org/documentation/cookbook/working-with-existing-databases.html

Here you can see a list of differences btw versions:

http://propelorm.org/documentation/whats-new.html